# Blurry image when using SKSpriteNode instead of sharp lines?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

An image is blurred when added to GameScene with SKSpriteNode.

Code:

```
    let circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spriteBackground")
    circle.position = CGPointZero
    cellLayer.addChild(circle)
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKIKo.jpg

Is the SKSpriteNode not configured properly?

Comment: Could be the anti-alias in the image.

Comment: You have to set its size.  init(texture texture: init(image image: UIImage),
            size size: CGSize)

Comment: That is the image I suppose that is too low resolution. If you only gonna have a white circle you can just use a SKShapeNode.

Comment: @Roecrew but if the size is set, doesn't it become rectangular and no longer circular?

Comment: Your image is always squared or rectangular,  there could be lots of problems, like is your scene scaling, and are you implementing 2x and 3x correctly?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon we need the image to be circular; are you saying there is a way to do this with textures as Roecrew suggested?

Comment: I am saying you load an image, it is always a square as far as the device is concerned,  making a circle image is fine,  I use circle images all the time, sprite kit supports circular collision.  I am suggesting you look at how you are rendoring your image,  what is the size of spirtebackground